# Stack a bar chart for a single series pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I know how to create a stacked bar chart using a dataframe with multiple rows, but is there a way to plot a series such that each index in the series in put into a stacked bar plot?

What I get is something like this:

[image: dodged bar graph]

Code:

```
series = pd.Series(3 * np.random.rand(4), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], name='series')
series.plot(kind = 'bar')
```

But what I want is to show a,b,c, and d all in one stacked bar graph. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not sure what you want since you haven't specified the desired output, but here is a try

```
pd.DataFrame(series).T.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this is the output I wanted, I tried to describe it as best I could. Your answer helped me figure it out thank you

Comment: @tarashypka: What is T?

Comment: @NaveenGabriel It’s transpose